# I only want Regex to only search spelling mistakes - how to exclude correct spellings?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

My goal is to identify a words/phrases which has been misspelt.

I want to exclude correct instances from my search.  The word I want to identify all misspellings of is "Whats'App" (with and without the apostrophe).

I want to identify instances when a letter has been swapped out for a number.

Here is my regex now which works well for all instances including correct spellings. **I want the code to exclude the following two words; whatsapp and whats'app.**

I am running this in Elastic.

```
wh[a4]t[s5]’?[a4]pp
```

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/crjgmh/3) help?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. The solution to this question was to exclude the correct instances by using `@&~(abc.+)`. I discovered the answer on [eslatics site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html).

Here is the query that now works;

```
wh[a4]t[s5]’?[a4]p+@&~(whats’?ap+)
```

Unfortunately, I have some unexpected results where some misspellings are not identified.  It must relate to a different problem in this query that I will post as a separate question.

Thanks,
Sean