# Regex Elastic Query not identifying not identifying all instances of a literal apostrophe is used

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

My goal is to identify all 'deliberate' misspellings of the words "whatsapp" and "whats'app" (where a and s is substituted for 4 and 5 and where an apostrophe may or may not have been used after the s/5). My query must exclude correct spelling instances of whatapp and whats'app.

...this query *almost* works;

```
wh[a4]t[s5]’?[a4]p+@&~(whats’?ap+)
```

It excludes correct spellings and identifies many misspellings where a's and s's are substituted for 4's and 5's and it allows for instances where only one or two p are used.

However, it is not identifying many instances when an apostrophe is used!
It will identify the likes of Wh4tsapp What5app Whats4pp Wh4t5app Wh4ts4pp and even Wh4ts’app but will not identify the likes of What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to match  with different types of quotes? `[Wh]h[a4]t[s5][’']?[a4]p+`

Comment: Hi The fourth bird. This is new to me. What is meant by different types of quotes when they both the same character ' and ' ?

Comment: Actually, your pattern matches the strings you say are not. Probably, you just really have straight quotes there. `[wW]h[a4]t[s5][’']?[a4]p+@&~([Ww]hats[’']?ap+)` might solve it

Comment: These two types are https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2019 and https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0027

Comment: Nice try Wiktor. What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp are still not identified...

Comment: Fourth bird. Thanks -  never appreciated there was a difference.  My keyboard only offers one of those.

Comment: You could try some more types of quotes ``[‘’“”`´"']`` Can you copy paste your quote on https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/ and see which one it is? Just to be sure, if you use `[Wh]h[a4]t[s5].?[a4]p+` it works right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I only want Regex to only search spelling mistakes - how to exclude correct spellings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048767/i-only-want-regex-to-only-search-spelling-mistakes-how-to-exclude-correct-spel)

Comment: Hi Fourth Bird. Yes! when I use [Wh]h[a4]t[s5].?[a4]p+ it works it identifies them all other than What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp.  I have tested the query in Regex101 -here is the query and the tests.  They all pass https://regex101.com/r/zcbbtV/2

Comment: BUT! It seems the four elusive items (What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp) only happen when I run the same query in elastic!!!

Comment: Wiktor it seems your variation works in regex101 but not when I go to elastic. In elastic it works for all other than What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp

Comment: @Sean I think it has something to do with how you are storing the text as `[Wh]h[a4]t[s5].?[a4]p+ it works it identifies them all other than What5’app Whats’4pp Wh4t5’app Wh4ts’4pp` See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html